# Grouping nested groups using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've got a object a bit like this:

```
{
   "FORD": [
     {
       "ManufacturerName": "FORD",
       "Model": "Focus",
       "Price": "12345"
     },
     {
       "ManufacturerName": "FORD",
       "Model": "KA",
       "Price": "11111"
     },
     {
      "ManufacturerName": "FORD",
      "Model": "Focus",
      "Price": "22222"
     }
   ],
   "HONDA": [
    {
        "ManufacturerName": "HONDA",
        "Model": "JAZZ",
        "Price": "98765"
      },
      {
        "ManufacturerName": "HONDA",
        "Model": "JAZZ",
        "Price": "33333"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've got this far using lodash code like this:

```
    let myTest = _.chain(obj)
       .sortBy('ManufacturerName')
       .groupBy('ManufacturerName')
```

What I'm trying to do also also group it by Model, so result will look something like this:

```
   {
      "FORD": [
        {
          "Focus": [
            {
              "ManufacturerName": "FORD",
              "Model": "Focus",
              "Price": "12345"
            },
            { 
              "ManufacturerName": "FORD",
              "Model": "Focus",
              "Price": "12345" }
          ],
          "KA": [
             {
               "ManufacturerName": "FORD",
               "Model": "KA",
               "Price": "11111"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "HONDA": [
          {
             "JAZZ": [
                { 
                  "ManufacturerName": "HONDA", 
                  "Model": "JAZZ", 
                  "Price": "33333" },
               { 
                  "ManufacturerName": "HONDA", 
                  "Model": "JAZZ", 
                  "Price": "98765" }
             ]
         }
      ]
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain your code? It doesn't make much sense for me. `obj` is an object,isn't it?

Comment: Yes. A Json object.

Comment: There is only one [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in JavaScript and your code would make even less sense for `obj === JSON`. I assume, you mean a JavaScript object. `sortBy` returns an array containing two arrays. Calling `groupBy` on it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Ok. I might not be using the correct terminology. The "obj" is json. The first block of code is where I'm up to following the _.chain. I'm just trying to work out how to group within a group. If you see what I mean.

Comment: JSON is a text format. _"The "obj" is json."_ means that `obj` is a string. `sortBy` and `groupBy` doesn't make sense on a string. You should probably read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation) It probably was a JSON string before you parsed it to a JavaScript object.

Comment: I was under the impression that json that is handled like json, IE. Not a string, where you access values and keys by dot notation, was regarded as an object. In much the same way an array is regarded as an object. Might be my misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, that's a misunderstanding. You can't access the keys and values of JSON in JavaScript, because JSON is a string in JavaScript. First, you have to parse it. After you've parsed it, it's a JavaScript object and not JSON anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map the object with `_.mapValues()` and group each each array (`v`) by the `Model`:

```js
const obj = {"FORD":[{"ManufacturerName":"FORD","Model":"Focus","Price":"12345"},{"ManufacturerName":"FORD","Model":"KA","Price":"11111"},{"ManufacturerName":"FORD","Model":"Focus","Price":"22222"}],"HONDA":[{"ManufacturerName":"HONDA","Model":"JAZZ","Price":"98765"},{"ManufacturerName":"HONDA","Model":"JAZZ","Price":"33333"}]}

const result = _.mapValues(obj, v => _.groupBy(v, 'Model'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Or using a chain:

```js
const obj = {"FORD":[{"ManufacturerName":"FORD","Model":"Focus","Price":"12345"},{"ManufacturerName":"FORD","Model":"KA","Price":"11111"},{"ManufacturerName":"FORD","Model":"Focus","Price":"22222"}],"HONDA":[{"ManufacturerName":"HONDA","Model":"JAZZ","Price":"98765"},{"ManufacturerName":"HONDA","Model":"JAZZ","Price":"33333"}]}

const result = _(obj)
  .mapValues(v => _.groupBy(v, 'Model'))
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Works like a dream. Many thanks.